# Small windows can't be resized (look pics for clarification)

Tags: release-loki

How to fix this?
Only the titles are visible, no options..
[image: Look at the warning popup]

[image: only title is visible]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Mutter or Gala, reported at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1623206).

Feel free to add more details and track the issue there.

Comment: The description on Launchpad mentions a dual monitor setup, is this only a problem for such a setup or does this affect single monitor setups too? I have one monitor (the laptop's one).

Answer (score 0):

You did not state if these windows opened up that way ... or if you did something to make them that way.

SO ...

Since I am at work right now I cannot test this out ... but ... did you try to double-click the title bar?

My recollection is that the first double-click will maximize the window
and the second double-click will resize it back to its default opening size.

Comment: They opened as in the picture and yes, i clicked on the title bar, nothing happens.

Comment: here's another picture, i purged and then installed the program just to be sure it's not me, when opening another option, this is how it opened.. http://imgur.com/hZhr0LQ